# How to generate random sentences in C using arrays?

Tags: c, string

I`m trying to generate random sentences but sometimes i got an error or it prints random characters.
Below is what i done. (the sentences should have the folowing format: article , noun , verb, preposition, article and noun).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {
srand(time(NULL));
    int r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6;
    char *article[] = {"the" , "a" , "one" , "some", "any"};
    char *noun[] = {"boy" , "girl" , "dog" , "town", "car"};
    char *verb[] = {"drove" , "jumped" , "ran" , "walked", "skipped"};
    char *preposition[] = {"to" , "from" , "over" , "under", "on"};

    r1 = rand() % 6; r2 = rand() % 6; r3 = rand() % 6;  r4 = rand() % 6; r5 = rand() % 6; r6 = rand() % 6;
    printf("%s %s %s %s  %s %s\n", article[r1], noun[r2], verb[r3], preposition[r4], article[r5], noun[r6]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what happens if you run your program?

Comment: For an array of e.g. five elements (like the `article` array), what are the valid indexes? What range do you create with `rand() % 6`?

Comment: Also, please [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 4):

```
r1 = rand() % 6;
```

have values `0,1,2,3,4,5`

But the first array has `5` elements. So you were accessing array index out of bound and were having undefined behavior.

Instead

```
r1 = rand() % arraysize;
```

This works.(Same you have to do for other arrays also).

So for example in the first case `arraysize = 5` so `r1= rand()%5` and for `r2=rand()%5` etc. (Here you have array size = 5 for all the arrays).

Getting the array size will be like this in this case

```
r2 = rand()%( sizeof noun/ sizeof noun[0] );
```

Answer (score 1):

All your lists have less than 6 elements, so from time to time, the random routine returns a value outside the list bounds: read a garbage pointer => undefined behaviour. So now the "random" bug is explained.

Now what happens when you (or another developper) add or remove elements to one list? you have to adjust sizes again.

I'd create a small macro to avoid doing that:

```
#define RANDSTRING(s) s[rand() % (sizeof(s)/sizeof(*(s)))]
```

now:

```
const char *r = RANDSTRING(noun);
```

picks a value in the `noun` list, guaranteed to be in bounds.

it works on lists of strings and computes the size correctly. It won't work on pointers on pointers like `char **`, though.

It also doesn't work on empty lists (`% 0` is illegal, and it makes no sense anyway)

Comment: @Yunnosch you're right. But the answer is the same :)

Comment: _was_ misleading. Now fixed

Comment: @chux better safe than sorry